# Good manners for C programming

Tags: c, memory-management, printf

I am currently programming my own implementation of `printf`, here is the code:

```
int my_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
        //Declare variable ou prog fonctionnel????
        va_list args;
        int numberValue;
        unsigned int unsignedNumberValue;
        double doubleValue;
        char* stringValue;
        char charValue;
        va_start(args, format);
        for(int i = 0; format[i]; i++){
                //This case is the most called case, so we test it first to get the
                //best perfs
                if(format[i] != '%'){
                        my_put_char(format[i]);
                }else{
                        if(format[i+1] == 'd' || format[i+1] == 'i'){
                                numberValue = va_arg(args, int);
                                my_put_nbr(numberValue);
                        }else if(format[i+1] == 'u'){
                                unsignedNumberValue = va_arg(args, unsigned int);
                                my_put_nbr_unsigned(unsignedNumberValue);
                        }else if(format[i+1] == 'o'){
                                numberValue = va_arg(args, int);
                                my_put_nbr_base(numberValue, 2); 
                        }else if(format[i+1] == 'c'){
                                //char parameters are passed as integer as va_args
                                charValue = va_arg(args, int);
                                my_put_char(charValue);
                        }else if(format[i+1] == 's'){
                                stringValue = va_arg(args, char*);
                                my_puts(stringValue);
                        }else if(format[i+1] == 'f'){
                                doubleValue = va_arg(args, double);
                                my_put_double(doubleValue);
                        }else if(format[i+1] == '%'){
                                my_put_char('%');
                        }else{
                                //error option not handled
                                char* error = my_strcat("\nThe option you provided is not a valid option: %", &format[i + 1], 1); 
                                write(2, error, sizeof(char) * my_strlen(error));
                        }
                        i++;    
                }
        }
        va_end(args);
        return 0;
}
```

I would like to know two things about my code:

- I wonder if i should code **"function way" programming** such as don't use variable and put `va_args` called directly in the `my_put` function. But doing this, it will allocate and free every loop instead of one declaration (allocation) who may not be used and one free at the end of the function. In big process I suppose it is better to store the returning value into a variable then recall "function way" the function. (for `strlen` on very big text for example)
- I would also like to know how to deal with functions that can be called with different types such as `my_put_nbr` in my code, can't I overload them? It seems that it must have  different name.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't know about CodeReview website, shall I move my post ?

Comment: C doesn't have function overloading.

Comment: With respect to your first question, if you don't want the intermediate variable, just write `my_put_double(va_arg(args, double));`. `va_arg(...)` is an ordinary expression; you aren't required to use it in an assignment statement. In general, you might want to consider using a `switch` statement rather than the long chain of `if...else if...`. The switch is more readable and sometimes faster.

Comment: I would like to know what is the more  efficient to do, for memory and speed. And in which cases, intermediate variable or functional programming should be used to get best results.

Comment: CodeReview is probably the best place for this.

Comment: Please note, if this is migrated to Code Review, the title should reflect on the purpose of the code, e.g *"A custom printf implementation"*.

Comment: @Qix with 5 upvotes, no downvotes and no close votes, it seems like it can fit on Stack Overflow too.

Comment: I can't see the point in optimizing printf for speed. You will spend ages in characters I/O anyway, so your gains will be neglectible even if you rewrite your code in assembly language. Optimizing for space might make sense on a very constrained architecture, let's say a 8/16 bits microcontroller with a few Kb of RAM & ROM.

Comment: Aside: your `printf` returns `0` but the standard library function returns the number of characters printed, or a negative value if an error occurs.

Comment: Pet peeve - in the `if(format[i] != '%'){`, if you put `continue;` then you can avoid an extra level of indent. Also this has nothing to do with performance, write the most readable code.

Comment: How does `my_strcat` work? If it mallocs space, you forgot to free it.

Comment: @SimonForsberg it's not off topic here. It's probably *more* on-topic over at CR.

Comment: Note: 1) should use `unsigned`, not `int` in `if(format[i+1] == 'o') { numberValue = va_arg(args, int);`  2) `char charValue;` --> `unsigned char charValue;`

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing printf for speed makes little sense, since the dominant execution time will be character I/O. Even a lightning fast format processing will not spare you the time needed to send your characters on their way.

The only thing arguably worth gaining here is size: stack size by avoiding another level of function call and code size by writing as few output functions as possible.

First thing to do to optimize your code is to turn your tests into a switch. Chances are the compiler will implement it as a table jump, which is more efficient than a bunch of tests. You can put the "most likely" formats first, but unless you can read the user's mind, it's rather hard to predict if he/she will rather display integers or floats or chars.

Passing variable number of parameters is the most expensive operation, so delegating the vararg processing to each atomic formatting function would only produce bulkier and slower code.

Instead, you would be better off writing your output code as inline functions and hope the compiler expands them to spare you another level of function call.

For the various possible argument sizes, the way to go is to cast all values into the biggest possible size (32 or 64 bits integers, floats or doubles depending on what you want to support) and have a limited number of functions do the display (signed integer / unsigned integer / double for instance).
Thus you will reduce both source and executable code size.

Comment: I was going to comment that the quickest operations should be processed first, but that is what OP has done mostly. The notable exception being `%c`.

Comment: This will be neglectible anyway. A switch will most probably be implemented as a table lookup jump, or whatever structure the compiler deems more efficient. Compared with the rest of the processing, this will gain nothing.

Comment: Not my downvote, but you seem to contradict yourself by saying that the processing method will gain little.

Comment: Little time, yes. The only thing arguably worth gaining here is size: stack size, by avoiding another level of function call and code size by writing as few output functions as possible.

Comment: But it's not recursive. Only one output function is called. the alternative will be one gigantic function very hard to follow.

Comment: No. Just make your functions inline and the compiler will generate this big huge function for you. Readable source, efficient code. Of course you have no guarantee the compiler will actually inline them. Still if they are simple enough there are good chances it will.